# Can saving a reference to an instance of Application lead to memory leaks?

Tags: android

saving the link to Activity will definetly lead to memory leak, but Application is singleton.
Can i save the link to Application?
Is it bad to keep the link to Application in my view model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing app context inside your ViewModel you can use [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel).

It is ok to keep instance of your app as static field in your overriden app class. It will not cause memory leak since the application context is around for the lifetime the app is running anyway.

I recommend you to take a look to the following article where simillar cases described - [Singletons in Android](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2015/07/14/why-static-references-to-application-contexts-are-probably-not-the-best-idea/)